# List of Facebook CDN addresses

Tags: facebook, cdn

I need to compile a list of the addresses of all the CDNs used by Facebook.

Example:

```
fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net
fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net
...
```

I need these for a captive portal application that allows user to connect to WiFi with facebook. We allow facebook.com through the firewall for Graph API calls, but one of the issues we had is that the Facebook login dialog takes forever to load and loads without stylesheets/images. We fixed that by white-listing fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net, but we want to make sure we won't have surprises later.

Comment: You will _always_ “have surprises later” if Facebook decides to add another CDN domain that you don’t have in your list yet …

Comment: Yes, we took that into account, and want to have the list downloaded regularly from our server, but still, we need a way to find all the CDN domains. Plus, while IP addresses can change often for CDNs, I believe that the domain names are pretty stable. They need to be to make sure that the FB scripts can access the resources they need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net

fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net 

fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net

fbcdn-creative-a.akamaihd.net

fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net
```

And:

```
fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net

fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net

fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net

fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net

fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net

fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net

fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net
```

Those start from character `A` and ends at `H`, if Facebook would add a new domain it must be like :

```
fbcdn-sphotos-i-a.akamaihd.net
```

So future CDN domains would be

```
fbcdn-sphotos-j-a.akamaihd.net

fbcdn-sphotos-k-a.akamaihd.net

fbcdn-sphotos-l-a.akamaihd.net

fbcdn-sphotos-m-a.akamaihd.net

fbcdn-sphotos-n-a.akamaihd.net
```

And So on.. till character `Z`

Comment: Thank you, this is a good answer, and what I was looking for. As a side note, I also added the domains defined in http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js, in "UrlMapConfig"

Answer (score 2):

`akamaihd` is used for old photos and for special photos(cover ph. example..) only as I see...

They created new servers and there is some new logic in them as well. Example:

`scontent-a-lhr.xx.fbcdn.net`
`scontent-b-lhr.xx.fbcdn.net` and more but I have seen some shared photos on interesting links. Example this:

```
https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/v/1472407_10151814939401656_1687041676_n.jpg?oh=d92bc9af7f987c5fe298ecc8c717a4e1&oe=5287894B&__gda__=1384659513_abeb3f33223e6e737aff91419149509e
```