# Facebook Authentication with limited internet access

Tags: facebook, authentication, wifi

We are a Wifi provider in South Africa. We want to allow users to create profiles using social media accounts.

When users register, they do not yet have internet access, so registering using facebook authentication is a bit of a mess as it needs internet access.

We can however, open up specific url's to the public.
I am not sure which url's I would need to open for the authentication to work.

Any help with the correct url's will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Facebook uses CDN (for static files CSS, JS and photos) with different URLs so make sure your include allow public access to these URLs found in this answer

- [List of Facebook CDN addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19573386/2151050)

Next you need to allow access to:

- `login` page

  ```
  http://www.facebook.com/login.php
  http://www.facebook.com/login

  https://www.facebook.com/login.php
  https://www.facebook.com/login
  ```
- `oAuth dialog` page to authenticate user with your app

  ```
  https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth
  http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth
  ```
- Facebook `Graph API`

  ```
  http://graph.facebook.com/
  https://graph.facebook.com/
  ```

Those are all URLs you need to authenticate users through a Wi-Fi hostspot.

Remember to block (don't ALLOW) access  to these URLs because users can login to their accounts and surf their `NewsFeed`

```
//www.facebook.com/home.php
//www.facebook.com/index.php

//m.facebook.com/*
//iphone.facebook.com/*
//beta.facebook.com/*
//touch.facebook.com/*
```

`//` means blocking both `HTTP` and `HTTPS`